# How can I kill the current app and open playstore?

Tags: android, android-intent

What I am trying to is... if the app is not using recent version, a dialog pops up and it lets the users know the app needs update. If they click `OK` button then `current app` is killed and `playstore` opens

This is what I implemented.

```
    private fun openPlaystoreAndKill() {
        try {
            startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=$packageName")))
        } catch (anfe: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$packageName")))
        }finally {
            killApp()
        }
    }

    /**
     * Kill the app forcefully
     */
    private fun killApp(){
//        finishAffinity()
        finishAndRemoveTask()
        System.runFinalizersOnExit(true)
        System.exit(0)
    }
```

1. finishAffinity() - This kills the activity. But not the process.
2. finishAndRemoveTask() - This kills the app. But The store doesn't open.
3. finishAffinity() + finishAndRemoveTask() - the same with 1.
4. finishAndRemoveTask() + finishAffinity() - the same with 2.

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Google released a month ago a library for detecting and prompting for app updates -- perhaps try it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Could you give me keywords for that?

Comment: https://joebirch.co/2019/05/07/exploring-in-app-updates-on-android/